# how to get options to choose post format in add new post

Tags: custom-post-types, posts

I've created a new post type gallery using CPT UI plugin, Now I want to add options to choose post Format and Featured Image in add new gallery post. 
Please check the attached screenshot. Could you please tell me how to get this option in add new post page.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all themes need to use `add_theme_support()` in the `functions.php` file to tell `WordPress` which post formats to support by passing an array of formats like so:

```
add_theme_support( 'post-formats', array( 'aside', 'gallery' ) );
```

***Note that you must call this before the init hook gets called! A good hook to use is the `after_setup_theme` hook.***

Then by code you can add the post formats like below-

```
//add post-formats to post_type 'your_custom_post_type'
add_post_type_support( 'your_custom_post_type', 'post-formats' );
```

Also can add support on creation of post type like below-

```
// register custom post type 'your_custom_post_type' with 'supports' parameter
add_action( 'init', 'create_your_post_type' );
function create_my_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 'your_custom_post_type',
      array(
        'labels' => array( 'name' => __( 'Products' ) ),
        'public' => true,
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'post-formats')
    )
  );
}
```

Comment: Should I add this code in wp-admin/admin-functions.php ?

Comment: Nope. Add those to your theme's `functions.php` file.

Comment: Thank you its working :) 
How about Featured Image option in add new gallery post ?

Comment: If this thing helped you will you please accept the answer. It would be very helpful. @SureshAlagar

Comment: Please help.
Check my answer below. I've created functions.php in my theme and added the code. But I am getting error message in my home page.

Comment: Do not use both the last two. Use the first of the last two if you already created the post type with code or any plugin. The last code block is to declaring the post formats on the creation of post. And as far I know you already created the post type. So the last block of code is invalid for you. I jut gave it as an information. And also change `your_custom_post_type` with your post type. Do not just copy and paste. Read the full answer first.

Answer (score 0):

When you will add new Custom Post Type using CPT UI plugin, you will see an option under **Settings -> Support -> Post Formats** in CPT UI Plugin.

[image]

Comment: Yes, choosen. Still it is not getting displayed in add new gallery post

Answer (score 0):

I've added the following code in funtions.php in my theme:

```
<?php

add_theme_support( 'post-formats', array( 'gallery', 'image', 'video' ) );

//add post-formats to post_type 'your_custom_post_type'
add_post_type_support( 'your_custom_post_type', 'post-formats' );

// register custom post type 'your_custom_post_type' with 'supports' parameter
add_action( 'init', 'create_your_post_type' );
function create_my_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 'your_custom_post_type',
      array(
        'labels' => array( 'name' => __( 'Products' ) ),
        'public' => true,
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'post-formats')
    )
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After adding post format support to your CPT:

```
function jt_add_post_type_support() {

   //add post-formats to post_type 'your_custom_post_type'
   add_post_type_support( 'your_custom_post_type', 'post-formats' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'jt_add_post_type_support', 10 );
```

You can modify it when this:
(*DO FORGET TO CHANGE "your_custom_post_type" to your CPT in both functions)

```
add_action( 'load-post.php',     'jt_post_format_support_filter' );
add_action( 'load-post-new.php', 'jt_post_format_support_filter' );
add_action( 'load-edit.php',     'jt_post_format_support_filter' );

function jt_get_allowed_project_formats() {
    //CHANGE TO THE ONES YOU WANT HERE:
    return array( 'standard', 'quote', 'image', 'video' );
}

function jt_default_post_format_filter( $format ) {

    return in_array( $format, jt_get_allowed_project_formats() ) ? $format : 'standard';
}

function jt_post_format_support_filter() {

    $screen = get_current_screen();

    // Bail if not on the projects screen.
    if ( empty( $screen->post_type ) ||  $screen->post_type !== 'your_custom_post_type' )
        return;

    // Check if the current theme supports formats.
    if ( current_theme_supports( 'post-formats' ) ) {

        $formats = get_theme_support( 'post-formats' );

        // If we have formats, add theme support for only the allowed formats.
        if ( isset( $formats[0] ) ) {
            $new_formats = array_intersect( $formats[0], jt_get_allowed_project_formats() );

            // Remove post formats support.
            remove_theme_support( 'post-formats' );

            // If the theme supports the allowed formats, add support for them.
            if ( $new_formats )
                add_theme_support( 'post-formats', $new_formats );
        }
    }

    // Filter the default post format.
    add_filter( 'option_default_post_format', 'jt_default_post_format_filter', 95 );
}
```